# Remove navigation menu item for model without removing ability to manage in RailsAdmin and CanCan?

Tags: cancan, rails-admin

So I have a model (Image) that belongs to another model (Product), and I want to allow a user to manage both of these two types of models, but I don't want to list the model in the navigation menu in RailsAdmin.

Basically of these two I only want Product to be visible in the navigation menu, while allowing the user to still crud their images within the edit/add form of a Product.

Is this possible with CanCan? Or do I need to use CSS to hide these navigation items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/202), and this [issue](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/986) your only valid approach would be the CSS approach

Comment: This is not true anymore, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40303561/1055045 below for the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

```
   config.model Team do
     visible false
    end
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Answer updated, people on here should accept this as the correct answer as it's more up to date and the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and unfortunately I haven't found any proper solution. The only workaround was to hack Rails Admin using javascript.

So, to hide the model Image from the navigation menu I added this code in 'app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/ui.js':

```
$(document).on('rails_admin.dom_ready', function() {
  $('ul.nav-pills li[data-model="image"]').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. fixed using this css

```
li[data-model="event_date"] {
display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your model:

```
rails_admin do
  visible false
end
```

no need to edit your rails_admin.rb file.